# Code design patterns for web other than MVC

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

Really I know never coding type(pattern) without MVC.
Now, I can create my own mvc but this is not enough for me.(With PHP) How I need to learn more thing.

How I need to learn for becoming Professional PHP developer?
I think I'll become premium member for killerphp, do you suggest?

Comment: The best way to learn is practice, and you don't need to buy anything for that.  Finding a good teacher helps though.

Comment: But I don't know how i need to know :)

Comment: see this will help you http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/howto/How-to-become-PHP-Developer.html

Comment: @HarshalMahajan this is for newbies :) I think I'm not a newbie.

Comment: than yusuf what you want? do you want to get a expertise in php or anythting else plz clear

Comment: @HarshalMahajan , please stop pointing to that horrifying page. It is like the collection of "what not to do".

Comment: @YusufAli , at the botto of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9855170/727208) you will find a collection of lectures and books. That should cover what you are looking for.

Comment: @HarshalMahajan That only hurts people. Please refrain from sharing those bad practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from knowing php or any other language itself it will be wise to start learning design patterns and object oriented design and analysis. i think that is what you want.
the two books i found great. and rest of the thing is implementing what you learnt and lot of practise.

**head first design pattern**

**head first OOA and OOD**