# Relative nested namespaces in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I'll try to describe the situation I'm having problems with:

I have one main folder. I keep all files in there (empty classes for a reason), and one sub-folder, containing the same files, with all implementations here (empty classes extend them).

the main folder's namespace is declared as `Project/Folder`, and the sub-folder as `Project/Folder/Subfolder`. These are class's declarations:

```
namespace Project\Folder;
class Foo extends Subfolder\Foo {  }

namespace Project\Folder\Subfolder;
class Foo {  }
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to call other classes from inside of the `Project\Folder\Subfolder\Foo` through these empty classes on the lower level, with only its name, e.g.:

```
namespace Project\Folder\Subfolder;
class Foo {
     function bar() {
        Another_Class::do_something();
     }
}
```

By default, there will be called `Another_Class` from the `Project\Folder\Subfolder` namespace. I want this to refer to Another_Class from the Project\Folder namespace with the same syntax - is that possible?

I hope I explained this clear enough, if not, write a commend, and I'll try to make it clearer.

Comment: I'm really curious what that reason is you need to put everything in 1 directory. I'm even more curious why you need those bodyless classes. Sounds more like a serious design issues rather than a legitimate use case to me tbh.

Comment: Empty classes...I was thinking of deleting them lately. Their purpose was to allow the users of my code to extend the functionality of original classes if they would want to, without messing the original code.

Comment: If users want to extend your classes they can just, well... `extend` them.

Comment: And, well...maybe not all classes...But in fact, ALMOST all of them. It's a framework, I've put there all basic classes for handling things like HTML, FORMS, but also classes which handle request flow, routing, etc. Didn't find any better solution here.

Comment: They can "extend" them of course. I just give them the right place to do this.

Comment: This coming from something where *all* classes are in the same directory I doubt it really is the right place ;-)

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to think about the design again, thanks for warning me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using the `use` statement.

```
use Project\Folder\Subfolder\Another_Class as SomeAlias;

// ...

SomeAlias::doSomething();

// or

$object = new SomeAlias();
$object->doSomething();
```

Alternatively, you would have to reference the entire namespace:

```
\Project\Folder\Subfolder\Another_Class::doSomething();

// or

$object = new \Project\Folder\Subfolder\Another_Class();
$object->doSomething();
```

[More information here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: But then I'd have to use that for all files in that namespace.

Comment: There's no some other way, right? I have a lot of these classes there.

Comment: Check my edit.  That is the only other way (that I'm aware of).

Comment: I'll have to choose the whole reference then, thanks. Is this the way they do this in "big" projects?

Comment: Yes I do this sometimes.  Unless I reference that class _a lot_ somewhere, in which case I use the first method.

Comment: Cool thing would be the possibility to use something like ../Another_Class::method().

Comment: Why are you using static method calls in the example? Do you really hate OOP so much?

Comment: @tereško Shouldn't I? Isn't it OOP either?

Comment: @user1615069 , do you know why it is called "object oriented" instead of "class oriented" programming?

Comment: Factory method is a known anti-pattern, which tries to force another set of responsibilities on the existing object. When used with polymorphism, it becomes an architectural black hole of complexity. And, of course, you are breaking the single responsibility principle. Also, your `framework::getConfig()` is just another example of global state.

Comment: What teresko said + You understand that makes stuff pretty hard to test right @azizpunjani. And you do test I or don't you?

Comment: @user1615069 , in that case, start by watching the lecture listed a the bottom of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9855170/727208) ... and the "how about singleton" is covered in the *Global State and Singletons* lecture.

Comment: @azizpunjani , you still have not provided any example without global state or violation of SOLID principles (assuming you even know what they are).

Comment: @everyone.  I only used static method calls because that's what the OP used.  Personally, I rarely use static methods.

Comment: @tereško the best explanation I've come across for static methods is this:  Does it makes sense to call this function even if no object has been instantiated?  If so, then using a static method makes sense; _however_, 99% of the time it's just an excuse to be _lazy_.

Comment: @mmmshuddup , can you come up with an example, or did you just left a 1% margin to yourself as *a way out*?

Comment: @tereško I never said the 1% was for _me_.  But I'm glad you asked, I created a simple class that uses microtime for a quick-n-dirty way to check execution time of small code blocks that utilizes static methods.  It was easier.  The class has _two_ methods, both of which are accessing static properties.  And even in this case, I used static methods because I _wanted_ to, not because it was the "correct" way.