# How to structure classes with frontend and backend (PHP)

Tags: php, oop

I have a question about how to structure classes. Lately I've been working on changing my PHP coding style over to newer standards since although I'm employed and do a lot of PHP coding for web apps, I'm starting to notice the way I code is rather old and frowned upon.
Here's a question.
If I have a small blog section on my website and have one class for blog (clsBlog.php) that does all the lifting to build my blog on the frontend, do I also store methods to upload the blog from the backend inside that class? I've usually just created a class called clsAdmin.php and had all the methods that the admin utility uses.

Comment: You might want to check how web mvc frameworks do it. Also It will be very beneficial I think to use a Framework like Symphony.

Comment: Stay away from frameworks. They should not be used as tool for learning OOP nor MVC pattern. It would be quite harmful in a long run if you do.

Answer (score 1):

You could have given us some examples of your current style. That would have let people to at least gage your current skill level.

I assume that the "frowned upon" style of programming, that you mentioned, can be described as "include based programming". Since I have never really used it, I cannot give you a clean & tested recipe for advancing.

The best I can offer you would be the list of links at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855170/727208). I would recommend to begin with ["PHP Object-Oriented Solutions"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430210117) book. Though, if you also have problems with newer PHP syntax, you might benefit from quickly skipping through ["Beginning PHP 5.3"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470413964).

Also, another thing you might look into might be the newer SQL API. There has begun a deprecation process for the ancient `mysql_*` functions. You should look into some [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). If you decide to go with PDO, then I would urge you to check [this tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).